# Trying to get URL list from infinite scroll site

Tags: scroll, infinite

I am trying to scrape data from an infinite scroll site. I need a list of URL's though to be able to parse the data I need. The site is http://www.cabinetparts.com/c/hinges/european-cabinet-hinges/standard-european-cabinet-hinges. I'm looking to find something like http://www.cabinetparts.com/c/hinges/european-cabinet-hinges/standard-european-cabinet-hinges#/Page=2... Page=3 etc. I was able to find this by inspecting the other infinite scroll sites in Chrome, but this site continues to elude me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to involve the inner workings of a specific website rather than being a self-contained programming question.

Comment: Is there a better place to post this question?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Have you tried `#pagebreak2`?

Comment: I did, but it won't load those page breaks until you've scrolled to the absolute bottom of the entire list allowing it to load every page as it goes.